# jquery plugin function parameter usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I stuck with this thing, the increment doesn't work and keep returning 0

```
var oft = 0;
$.fn.load = function(oft){
       oft = oft+2;
}

$('#check').click(function(){
    $(this).load(oft);
    alert(oft);
});
```

until I change the parameter name like this,

```
var oft = 0;
$.fn.load = function(offset){ /*name changed*/
       oft = offset+2;
}

$('#check').click(function(){
    $(this).load(oft);
    alert(oft);
});
```

just curious, why is it? clear explanation will be very appreciated, Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line that does the trick.

```
$.fn.load = function(oft){ /*name changed*/
```

In javascript the parameter variables has local scope. Even if you change it inside the function the outside world will not see it.

So when you are calling *load* function using following click callback function, it always get this value *var oft = 0*;

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    $(this).load(oft);
    console.log(oft);
});
```

But when you are changing the parameter name to *offset* then this *offset* gets the local scope and the variable *oft* has the global scope inside load function. As the variable *oft* has global scope, you are able to see the increment inside click callback function.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of local and global variable scopes.

You define oft outside of the function so it has a global scope. Then, you define a local version of oft by passing it in as a parameter.

Javascript then uses the local version which has the same name. It did the operation to the local variable and then when the function ended that variable went away. They have the same name but they are not the same variable.

You can read more here: [Why does local variable kill my global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499120/why-does-local-variable-kill-my-global-variable)